# Retain function properties with javascript bind method

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, bind

The javascript `bind` method returns a bound object however the returned object contains none of properties of the original object.

In case the property is set on the prototype object, I can use `Object.setPrototypeOf` to restore all the properties, however I can't figure out how to do the same for properties on the function itself.

```
var obj = function(){/*some code logic */}
obj.a = 1;
var boundedObj = obj.bind(obj);
boundedObj.a; //returns undefined

var boundedObj2 = Number.bind(Number);
boundedObj2.EPSILON// returns undefined
Object.setPrototypeOf(boundedObject2, Number); 
boundedObj2.EPSILON // returns the epislon value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()` to copy all the enumerable, own properties to the bound function.

```js
var obj = function(){/*some code logic */}
obj.a = 1;
var boundedObj = obj.bind(obj);
Object.assign(boundedObj, obj)
console.log(boundedObj.a);
```

Comment: also `obj.bind({...obj})` or `obj.bind(Object.assign({}, obj))`

Comment: Those don't work, because `{...}` and `Object.assign()` create ordinary objects, not `Function` exotic objects.

Comment: Isn't binding a function to an ordinary object what creates an exotic function object?

Comment: The issue is that your argument to `bind()` is not the original `obj` function.

Comment: I'm talking about the exotic object created by `var obj = function() {}`

Comment: You're right. Sorry for debating. I was messing around in my console and somehow got that to work, but it was due to using object.assign and I didn't realize it.

Comment: No problem, I had to try it out to assure myself it wouldn't work.